# Power to ceiling light when switch is off

Tags: electrical, switch, ceiling

I have changed the old light fixture to a new one.

When I turn off the switch the light bulbs have a slight glow in them as there’s still power going to them and stay like this until the light is switched back on.

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: Are the new bulbs LED perchance?

Comment: Hey, free nightlight.

Comment: Is the switch lighted or just a simple switch?

Comment: It’s just a normal switch